# How do I make two dependent POST calls in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, types

I have one HTTP POST call to create a moratorium. The second post call will try to use a moratoriumID (returned from the first call) to insert a series of moratorium locations. I've been searching around and the answer seems to be in service use switchMap() within .pipe() . Is this correct? 
If so, why am I getting the following error:

```
Argument of type '(dataFromSvc1: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2345)
```

See code and image below.

```
PostMoratorium(moratoriumtopost: Moratorium,moratoriumLocationstopostarray: MoratoriumLocation[]): Observable<number> {
const PostMoratoriumUrl = `${this.moratoriumUrl}`;

return this.apiService.postWithLocalErrorHandling(PostMoratoriumUrl, moratoriumtopost)
  .pipe(
     //I get the error here with dataFromSvc1 underlined !
    switchMap(dataFromSvc1 => {
      const PostMoratoriumLocationsUrl = `${this.moratoriumUrl}/moratorium/${dataFromSvc1}/location`;
      moratoriumLocationstopostarray.forEach(giveMoratoriumId);

      function giveMoratoriumId(item) {
        const moratoriumlocationtopost = {
          county:item.county ,
          city:item.city,
          zip:item.zipCode,
          moratoriumId:dataFromSvc1,
        } as MoratoriumLocation;
        return this.apiService.postWithLocalErrorHandling(PostMoratoriumLocationsUrl,moratoriumlocationtopost);      
      }  
    }
    )//switchMap
  );//pipe
```

}

[image]

Comment: You say your function overall should return `Observable<number>`, but you don't return anything from the switchMap callback (and `forEach` doesn't return anything anyway). Also `\`${this.moratoriumUrl}\`` seems pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `concatMap` for requests that need to be made in order and depend on the previous value. You can read more about it [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap)

```
PostMoratorium(moratoriumtopost: Moratorium,moratoriumLocationstopostarray: MoratoriumLocation[]): Observable<number> {

   const PostMoratoriumUrl = `${this.moratoriumUrl}`;
   return this.apiService.postWithLocalErrorHandling(PostMoratoriumUrl, moratoriumtopost)
      .pipe(concatMap(dataFromSvc1 => {
          const PostMoratoriumLocationsUrl = `${this.moratoriumUrl}/moratorium/${dataFromSvc1}/location`;
          moratoriumLocationstopostarray.forEach(giveMoratoriumId);
          const moratoriumlocationtopost = {
             county: item.county,
             city: item.city,
             zip: item.zipCode,
             moratoriumId: dataFromSvc1
          } as MoratoriumLocation;

          return this.apiService.postWithLocalErrorHandling(PostMoratoriumLocationsUrl,moratoriumlocationtopost);      
      }  
    }
    )
  );
```

Let me explain what's happening here:

1. `this.apiService.postpostWithLocalErrorHandling(PostMoratoriumUrl, moratoriumtopost)` gets called and will return a value.
2. This value is made available in the callback function of `.concatMap` as `dataFromSvc1`.
3. We now use this data to do some further processing
4. And we return `this.apiService.postWithLocalErrorHandling(PostMoratoriumLocationsUrl,moratoriumlocationtopost);` since the callback of `concatMap` (just like `switchMap`) expects an observable. This Http call is now made.

Always use `concatMap` for chains of observables that depend on previous input and require an order of execution.

Hope this helps